# samba problem on 19.10

Tags: samba, windows-10, 19.10

I installed 19.10 and used the smb.conf file I used with 18.0 and now I have problems with Windows 10 machines having access to the shared files. When I try to access the file it asks for username and password I put in the user name from the config file and the lynus password but it gives me an error of Access is denied. From the same Windows machine I can access shared files on an 18.04 machine

Answer (score 1):

> When I try to access the file it asks for username and password I put
>   in the user name from the config file and the lynus password but it
>   gives me an error of Access is denied.

You don't pass the Linux password to samba you pass the samba password to samba. Did you add that user to the samba password database? As in:

```
sudo smbpasswd -a linux-user-name
```

The password itself may be the same as the login password but you still have to add it to samba.

Comment: I had put in the config file to sync the passwords but that did not do what I thought. Your answer is the magic bullit. It all works now. Thank you.